# ARM assembly code

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm beginner in ARM architecture. I have a programm on assembler (ARM arch) and I must what's mean every string in the programm. What does it mean? I can't find information about it. Help me, please. Thank u.

```
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 40
@ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
fstmfdd>sp!, {d8, d9}
bl<>__aeabi_l2d
it eq
fmdrr<->d6, r0, r1
fdivd<->d7, d8, d6
faddd<->d9, d9, d7
flds<-->s11, [sp, #4]<->@ int
.word<->0
```

Comment: I hope I'll remember to answer after my lunch. Anyway I'd recommend the book "Pro Android Apps Performance Optimization" for Android architectures (ARM - normal and Thumb mode and x86)

Comment: Is your question "what does every line of this program mean?"?

Comment: See the [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](http://morrow.ece.wisc.edu/ECE353/arm_reference/ddi0100e_arm_arm.pdf) and [the ARM infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0274h/Chdgifab.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FMDRR` transfers data from two ARM1136 registers to a VFP11 (vertex floating-point) double-precision register. In this case it transfers the bits from registers r0 and r1 to form a double-precision (`double` variable) value in VFP11 register d6.

`FDIV` is floating-point divide, the "D" at the end is the "double" precision flag since you're dividing two values of type double. In this case `d7 = d8 / d6`

`FADD` is floating-point addition, similar to the previous command. In this case `d9 = d9 + d7`

`FLD` is floating-point load, the "S" at the end is the "single" precision flag since you're passing the value with the length of a single CPU-word. The [sp, #4] means that you're loading the data that is stored 4 words after the sp (e.g. if register sp is 100th word you get 104th word). The @int is the conversion flag. In this case `s11 = [sp+4]`

Check the [ARM Information Center](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp) for additional reference.